# Unable to get hidden field value in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a hidden field in my asp file, and I have assigned value for the hidden field by using a JavaScript function. However, I wasn't able to get the value.

I have to get the hidden field value and pass to a query.

My JS code:

```js
function checkboxlimit() {
    for (j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++)
    {
        if (checkboxes[j].checked == true)
        {
            alert(checkboxes[j].value)// this one coming?
            document.getElementById("Hidden1").value = checkboxes[j].value
            alert("Check" +document.getElementById("Hidden1").value)
        }
    }
}
```

HTML and ASP:

```html
Do Until RS.EOF%>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="center" class="style1">
        <input  type="checkbox" name="CompanyID_Merge" value="<%=RS("CompanyID")%>" onchange="checkboxlimit();" />
    </td>
    <td valign="middle" align="center"  class="style1">
        <a href="/main/league_info/companies/company_info.asp?CompanyID=<%=RS("CompanyID")%>"target="_blank"><%=RS("CompanyName")%></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<%               
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
%>
</table>
<%
End If
RS.Close
SET RS = Nothing
Conn.Close
%>
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" name="CompanyID_hidden" runat="server" value=""/> 
<% 
    CompanyID_Merge=Request.Form("CompanyID_hidden")
    Response.Write("chk" & Request.Form("CompanyID_hidden"))
    Conn.Open strConn
    SQL = "SELECT"
    SQL = SQL & " Projects.CompanyID, Projects.ProjectID, Projects.ProjectName, Projects.SeasonYear, Seasons.Season, Activities.ActivityName,"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM Projects"
    SQL = SQL & " AND ProjectAssociations.RenewedProjectID = " & CheckNumber(ProjectID)
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE Projects.CompanyID = " & CheckNumber(CompanyID_Merge)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value, server side, only after submitting the form, or using AJAX.

That said, you don't need to assign the checkbox value to hidden field, you can get the value of all selected checkboxes in classic ASP by using the name:

```
<%
    Response.Write("selected " & Request.Form("CompanyID_Merge").Count & " items<br />")
    For x=1 To Request.Form("CompanyID_Merge").Count
        Response.Write(Request.Form("CompanyID_Merge").Item(x) & "<br />")
    Next
%>
```